# Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\FileController::store(), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected using laravel 6

Tags: php, laravel, validation

I want to insert data files used (array $ data) in store method like that of RegisterController.php create method with validation system but it gives me error

> Too few arguments to function App \ Http \ Controllers \ FileController :: store ( ), 0 passed and exactly 1 expected.

**FileController.php**

```
 public function store(array $data)
    {
        $file = new File();
        $jdate = Carbon::now();
        $request = app('request');
        if ($request->hasFile('image')) {
            $image = $request->file('image');
            $imagee = Crypt::encryptString($image);
            $image->storeAs("public\profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year,$imagee.'.'.$image->extension());
            $file->image = "profiles\\".$jdate->format('F').$jdate->year."\\".$imagee.'.'.$image->extension(); 
        }
        $im = $file->image;
        $validator = Validator::make($data, [
            'category_id'=> ['bail','required'],
            'titre'      => ['bail','exclude_unless:category_id,1', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'name'       => ['bail','exclude_unless:category_id,1', 'string', 'min:3', 'max:255'],
            'last'       => ['bail','exclude_unless:category_id,1', 'string', 'min:2', 'max:255'],
            'image'      => ['bail','mimes:jpeg,jpg,png,gif,svg','exclude_unless:category_id,1','max:2048'],
        ]);
        return File::create([
            'category_id'  => $data['category_id'],
            'titre'        => $data['titre'], 
            'name'         => $data['name'],
            'last'         => $data['last'], 
            'image'        => $im 
        ]);
        return Redirect::to("/")
        ->withSuccess('Great! file has been successfully uploaded.');
    }
```

Comment: I think it would be `store(Request $request, $data)` because you call the `Request` on your function an also `$data`

Comment: @sta thx for u answer ,i add $data but not work always some error

Comment: Yes, because you need to pass arguments

Comment: It could simply be because you've not defined a parameter for that route or when you're calling it yourself. Would a default empty array parameter help? E.g. `store(array $data = [])`. Or are you trying to fetch the data from the request? In that case, drop the `$data` parameter and add `$data = $request->all()`.

Answer (score 1):

Getting data from a form you need to instantiate the Request:

```
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;


public function store(Request $request)
{
   ......
```

Answer (score 0):

In `RegisterController` there is a trait called `RegistersUsers` that process the request values and then send them to `create` method of `RegisterController` to create new `User`. In your case your store method expects a parameter but you are not passing that parameter from any where. You have to use `Request` class to get get or post request data or you can use `request()` global helper.

if you use class then it is like

```
use \Illuminate\Http\Request;

public function store(Request $request)
{
    $a = $request->a;
}
```

or if you use helper function

```
public function store()
{
    $a = request('a');
}
```